# CSS transition opacity on elements with defined opacity

Tags: jquery, css, css-transitions, opacity

I have buttons with opacity 0 and I want to transition them to opacity 1 with delay. Some buttons have `selected` class (that gives them `opacity: 0.35;`). The problem is that when transition starts, these buttons with `selected` class are already visible. Instead they should fade from opacity 0 to 0.35 (like other buttons fade from opacity 0 to 1). Is this possible to achieve this or should I use something else for `selevted` than opacity?

```js
var fade_arr = []
var btns = $('.a').each(function() {
  fade_arr.push($(this))

})
var p = 0,
  len = fade_arr.length,
  z;
for (z = 0; z < len; z++) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    fade_arr[p].addClass('visible');
    p++;
  }, 50 + (z * 50));
}
```

```css
.a {
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  float: left;
  margin: 5px;
  background: #999;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1s;
}

.a.selected {
  opacity: 0.35;
}

.visible {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="a"></div>
  <div class="a"></div>
  <div class="a"></div>
  <div class="a selected"></div>
  <div class="a selected"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: use `.selected.visible {opacity: 0.35}` to only apply it when both classes are defined for the element

Comment: Regarding the delay, you could just add `transition-delay: 1s;` instead of doing javascript.

Comment: @Dejan.S - that is not the same, I am delaying each transition from the previous one.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your CCS elements

```
transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
```

or add different classes like

```
.selected {
opacity:1;
transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}

.unselected {
opacity: 0.3;
transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}
```

Then add or remove the class. You can add and remove from all children instead of individually like

```
$('.youclass').addclass(selected).siblings().addclass('unselected);
```